# C++ binary operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As per Deitel's 9ed C++ How to program, p. 439-440:

> A binary operator can be overloaded as a non-static member function
>   with one parameter or as a non-member function with two parameters
>   (one of those parameters must be either a class object or a reference
>   to a class object).

So, what other sort of object is there beside a class object or a reference to a class object? I cannot think of anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, what other object is there beside class object or a reference to a class object?

There are fundamental types defined by the language, such as `int`, `double`. Instances of fundamental types are also objects.

Let's say you have:

```
struct Foo { ... };
```

You can overload the `operator+` function as non-member functions

```
Foo operator+(Foo , int);
Foo operator+(Foo& , int);
Foo operator+(int, Foo);
Foo operator+(int, Foo&);
```

etc. In all these cases, one of the arguments is a `Foo` or a `Foo&`. It can also be `Foo const&`. However, you cannot overload

```
int operator+(int, int);
```

since neither of the argument types is a class or a reference to a class.

Comment: Foo operator+(const Foo& , int);  or Foo operator+(const Foo& , const Foo&);

Comment: Perhaps more relevantly, you cannot define operators for non-class types even if no built-in operator for them exists, such as `int operator<< (double, double)`.

Comment: In the language of the Standard, raw pointers and raw arrays are also considered objects. The only types that are not object types are function types, reference types, and (cv) `void` ([basic.types]/7). But the meaning of "object" can be less clear in other contexts.

Answer (score 9):

It means you can't (re)define the built-in operators like `int operator+(int a, int b);`. Note that the description is incomplete, one or both parameters can also be an `enum`.

Answer (score 4):

In support to @user657267's answer,

From [over.match.oper/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.oper):

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a
>   **class** or an **enumeration**, the operator is assumed to be a built-in
>   operator and interpreted according to [expr.compound]

```
struct String {
  String (const String&);
  String (const char*);
  operator const char* ();
};

String operator+ (const String&, const String&);

void f() {
 const char* p = "one" + "two";  // ill-formed because neither operand has class or enumeration type
 int I = 1 + 1;                  // always evaluates to 2 even if class or enumeration types exist
                                 // that would perform the operation.
}
```

Thus, overloading `operator+` on primitive data types is ill-formed.

Answer (score -1):

It is a verbose doc. It implies that at least one operand of the static binary operator must be of current class (reference/value) type; otherwise it is considered an irrelevant operator.